# Date formating showing as undefined, NaN in Safari only

Tags: javascript

I have a date formatting issue in Safari.  This works for me in all other browsers but not safari as it shows undefined, NaN.

```js
const MONTHS = {
    0: 'January',
    1: 'February',
    2: 'March',
    3: 'April',
    4: 'May',
    5: 'June',
    6: 'July',
    7: 'August',
    8: 'September',
    9: 'October',
    10: 'November',
    11: 'December',
};           

let x = {};
x.created_at = "2021-01-19 18:12:43".replace(/\s/, 'T')

const dateArr = new Date(x.created_at); 
const year = dateArr.getFullYear();
const month = dateArr.getMonth();
const day = dateArr.getDate();

const formattedDate = MONTHS[month] + ' ' + day + ', ' + year;

x.formattedDate = formattedDate;

let div = document.querySelector('div');
div.innerHTML = `date is ${x.formattedDate}`
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I am having a date formatting issue but only in Safari browsers.  I have a const defined:

Comment: So this is a JS issue. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and make a [mcve] of JUST the object and the conversion code. This is not a VUE issue. We need to see `x.created_at`

Comment: Does it work if you use a `T` instead of a space to separate the date and time parts in `x.created_at`?  (try a simple string replace if necessary).

Comment: @mplungjan - No, the dashes should remain.  Refer to https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-time-string-format

Comment: done, I just made a working JS only sample that will work in browsers except Safari

Comment: And now `.replace(/ /,"T")`